# .htaccess - 3 different rewrites for 3 different URL structures

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve the following using htaccess on my blog portal:

**STRUCTURE 1**

example.domain.com/link/sublink -> /blogdisplay.php?page=example&page2=link&page3=sublink

**STRUCTURE 2**

en.domain.com/link/sublink/subsublink -> /index.php?lang=en&page=link&page2=sublink&page3=subsublink

**STRUCTURE 3**

domain.com/link/sublink/subsublink -> /index.php?page=link&page2=sublink&page3=subsublink

How do I achieve this? This is my current code (which doesn't handle languages at all right now, but the two other URL structures work fine):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,})\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1&page2=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1&page2=$1&page3=$2 [L,QSA]

## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For language case you can add this additional case (just below R=301 rule):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=%1&page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**PS:** Also I suggest moving `If the request is for a valid file` rule just below above language rule.

Comment: Shall I move it below or above? (You said below above language rule)

Comment: below my `above suggested rule` :) Sorry for confusing language. Even if you place `If the request is for a valid file rule` at top it will be fine.